# Accessing siteminder environment variables using python

Tags: apache, python-2.7, mod-wsgi, siteminder

I am running apache 2.4 with siteminder. I am able to access certain variables set by siteminder using perl cgi script. Examples of these variables are HTTP_SMUNIVERSALID, HTTP_SMUSERDN, HTTP_SMSERVERSESSIONID and so on. Here is my perl cgi script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI;
print CGI::header();

foreach my $key (sort(keys(%ENV))) {
    print "$key = $ENV{$key}<br>\n";
    }
```

I configured my apache to run python with mod_wsgi and my hello world application works as per the instructions [here](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-configuration-guide.html) I can see that it is going through siteminder by the cookies it sets. However my script below doesn't output siteminder variables that I am able to see through PERL cgi script above.

```
import os

def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = b'Hello World!\n'
    envs = ''
    for k, v in os.environ.items():
        envs = envs + str(k) + "=" + str(v) + "\n";
    output = output + envs
    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

Comment: How CGI scripts work is different. When using mod_wsgi any variables will be in the per process ``environ`` dictionary given as argument, not the process wide``os.environ``. Did you check in ``environ``?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton, thanks a lot, this worked! I didn't know there is something called environ that I could access, I was just accessing it the regular python way. If you put this as an answer I would be glad to accept it.